# How to generate Google Chart inside a ViewModel Loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Is there a way to dynamically generate a google chart while looping through a ViewModel?

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.CompanyList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.companyName
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="chart-div"></div> //chart right here
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p>@item.sales.ToString(numberDisplayFormat)</p>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
```

I have a method in my controller that returns json-formatted data, and it works just fine for charts outside of this loop.

I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try ? What is that ?

Comment: You likely need a unique id for each div that's created by the loop.

Comment: @Shyju No error, I just can't make the chart generate as many charts as how many time my foreach loops.